# Fastest way to run specific simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have versions of simulator start from 9.3 up to 10.3.1. It's very large amount of simulators, but almost all the time i use 3 of 4 of them.

[image]

So, the question is, does Xcode have the fastest way to run app on specific simulator? Maybe create keybindings or some script or framework can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost 5 years of the question, Xcode 14 now has a `Recent` section in the Device panel:

[image: Recent section]

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 9, you can Open up Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators, and you can remove the ones you don't want from the run destinations list.

In earlier versions, you can just delete the ones that you don't want.

There is no way to assign keybindings to specific run destinations.